# Recursive query?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hello everybody i'm currently stuck with a query for an ssrs report.

The database is a ticket registration for an helpdesk. So every day techs from the cds team log tickets. If they couldn't resolve the ticket they send it to an other team.
I'm looking for a query who retrace the backlog (non closed tickets) for each month and each team at the end of the month.

Ex :
May 26 17h ticket open by the helpdesk
May 27 8h ticket goes to Techsupport N2
June 3 ticket goes to Tech N3
July 2 ticket closed

I need to retrieve this :
Helpdesk May 0 June 0
N2 May 1 June 0
N3 May 0 June 1

database structure :

| Table Appel |
| --- |
| Noappel |
| C_equipe (last affected team) |

| Table actions |
| --- |
| Noappel |
| Noaction |
| type_action (affect when goes to an other team Clos when closed) |
| C_equipe (team who done the action) |

i made something based on a query found on the web but it works on weeks not months.

```
DECLARE @DR DATETIME
DECLARE @SM INTEGER
SET @SM=5
SET @DR=getdate()
SELECT T.* FROM (SELECT A.IDT_APPEL AS NOTICKET,
           DEBUT.C_ACTION   AS C_DEBUT,
           FIN.C_ACTION     AS C_FIN,
           RS.DF_SEM        AS F_TEST,
           RS.NUM_SEMAINE   AS NUM_SEMAINE,
           E.L_EQUIPE   AS EQUIPETICKET,
           EP.L_EQUIPE AS EQUIPESUP,
           A.C_UTIL_INT,
           CONCAT(util.N_UTIL,' ',util.PRE_UTIL)  AS INTERVENANT,
            
           CASE
             WHEN Datepart(ISO_WEEK, FIN.D_CREATION) = RS.NUM_SEMAINE
                  AND Datediff(DAY, FIN.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 7
                  AND FIN.C_TACTION = 'SYS_EQUIPE'
                  AND Isnull(UTIL.C_ISIPARC, '0') <> '666' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END              AS COND_TR,
           CASE
             WHEN Datepart(ISO_WEEK, FIN.D_CREATION) = RS.NUM_SEMAINE
                  AND Datediff(DAY, FIN.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 7
                  AND FIN.C_TACTION = 'SYS_EQUIPE'
                  AND Isnull(UTIL.C_ISIPARC, '0') = '666' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END              AS COND_REJ,
           CASE
             WHEN FIN.C_TACTION IN('SYS_CLOS_TECH','SYS_CLOS')
                  AND Datepart(ISO_WEEK, FIN.D_CREATION) = RS.NUM_SEMAINE
                  AND Datediff(DAY, FIN.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 7 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END              AS COND_CLOS,
           CASE
             WHEN Datepart(ISO_WEEK, DEBUT.D_CREATION) = RS.NUM_SEMAINE
                  AND Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 7 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END              AS NB_TICKET_ENTRE,
           CASE
             WHEN ( ( FIN.D_CREATION IS NULL
                       OR FIN.D_CREATION > RS.DF_SEM )
                    AND DEBUT.D_CREATION < RS.DF_SEM ) THEN ( CASE 
                                                                WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) - 2 < 5 THEN '05'
                                                                WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) - 2 >= 5
                                                                     AND Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) - 2 < 10 THEN '10'
                                                                WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) - 2 >= 10
                                                                     AND Datediff(MONTH, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 1 THEN '30'
                                                                WHEN Datediff(MONTH, DEBUT.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) >= 1 THEN '30+'
                                                                ELSE NULL
                                                              END )
             ELSE NULL
           END              AS F_NONCLOS,
           CASE
             WHEN Datepart(ISO_WEEK, FIN.D_CREATION) = RS.NUM_SEMAINE
                  AND Datediff(DAY, FIN.D_CREATION, RS.DF_SEM) < 7 THEN ( CASE 
                                                                            WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) < 1 THEN '01'
                                                                            WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) >= 1
                                                                                 AND Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) < 2 THEN '02'
                                                                            WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) >= 2
                                                                                 AND Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) < 5 THEN '05'
                                                                            WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) >= 5
                                                                                 AND Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) < 15 THEN '15'
                                                                            WHEN Datediff(DAY, DEBUT.D_CREATION, FIN.D_CREATION) >= 15 THEN '15+'
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                          END )
             ELSE NULL
           END              AS F_CLOS,
           DEBUT.D_CREATION AS DEBUT,
           FIN.D_CREATION   AS FIN,
           RS.YEAR AS YEARS
    FROM   APPEL A
           INNER JOIN (SELECT B.NO_APPEL,
                              B.C_ACTION,
                              B.D_CREATION,
                              B.C_EQUIPE,
                              B.C_TACTION,
                              Lead(B.C_ACTION, 1)
                                OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY B.NO_APPEL
                                  ORDER BY B.C_ACTION) AS FIN_C_ACTION
                       FROM   ACTIONS B WITH (NOLOCK)
                       WHERE  B.C_TACTION IN ( 'SYS_EQUIPE', 'SYS_CLOS_TECH', 'SYS_REOUVERT','SYS_CLOS' )
                              AND ( CAST(B.D_CREATION AS DATE)< Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, 0, @DR)), 0) )) DEBUT
                   ON ( A.NO_APPEL = DEBUT.NO_APPEL
                        AND DEBUT.C_EQUIPE IN('ETUD_MET_BILIZI')
                        
                        AND DEBUT.C_TACTION IN( 'SYS_EQUIPE', 'SYS_REOUVERT' ) )
           LEFT JOIN ACTIONS FIN WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON ( FIN.C_ACTION = DEBUT.FIN_C_ACTION )
           LEFT JOIN UTILISATEUR UTIL WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON ( UTIL.C_UTIL = FIN.C_UTIL )
           INNER JOIN EQUIPE E WITH (NOLOCK)
                  ON DEBUT.C_EQUIPE = E.C_EQUIPE
       INNER JOIN EQUIPE EP WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON E.C_EQUIPE_PERE = EP.C_EQUIPE
           INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Datepart(ISO_WEEK, P.D_JOUR)                                                                                                     AS Num_semaine,
                                       Dateadd(SECOND, 59, Dateadd(MINUTE, 59, Dateadd(HOUR, 23, Dateadd(DAY, -1, Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, P.D_JOUR) + 1, 0))))) AS DF_SEM,
                                       YEAR(P.D_JOUR) AS YEAR
                       FROM   PLANNINGS P WITH (NOLOCK)
                              INNER JOIN TCALEND TC WITH (NOLOCK)
                                      ON TC.C_TCALEND = P.C_TCALEND
                                         AND TC.F_TCALENDSTD = 1
                       WHERE  ( C_TPERIOD <> 3
                                AND C_TPERIOD <> 9 )) RS
                   ON ( ( FIN.D_CREATION > Dateadd(DAY, -7, RS.DF_SEM)
                           OR FIN.D_CREATION IS NULL )
                        AND (CAST( RS.DF_SEM AS DATE) >= Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, - @SM, @DR)), 0)
                              AND CAST(RS.DF_SEM AS DATE) <= Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, 0,@DR)), 0) ) )
    WHERE  (A.C_NATURE = 'INC' OR A.C_NATURE = 'DMD')
           AND ( A.D_CLOTTECH >= Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, - @SM, @DR)), 0)
                  OR A.D_CLOTTECH IS NULL )
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT NULL                                                                                                                             IDT_APPEL,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             C_DEBUT,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             C_FIN,
                    Dateadd(SECOND, 59, Dateadd(MINUTE, 59, Dateadd(HOUR, 23, Dateadd(DAY, -1, Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, P.D_JOUR) + 1, 0))))) AS DF_SEM,
                    Datepart(ISO_WEEK, P.D_JOUR)                                                                                                     AS Num_semaine,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             EQUIPETICKET,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             EQUIPESUP,
        NULL                                                                 C_UTIL_INT,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             INTERVENANT,
                    0                                                                                                                                COND_TR,
                    0                                                                                                                                COND_REJ,
                    0                                                                                                                                COND_CLOS,
                    0                                                                                                                                NB_TICKET_ENTRE,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             F_NONCLOS,
                    NULL                                                                                                                             F_CLOS,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    --YEAR(P.D_JOUR) AS YEARS
                    case when Datepart(ISO_WEEK, P.D_JOUR)=1 then YEAR(getdate()) ELSE YEAR(P.D_JOUR) end   AS YEARS                        
    FROM   PLANNINGS P WITH (NOLOCK)
           INNER JOIN TCALEND TC WITH (NOLOCK)
                   ON TC.C_TCALEND = P.C_TCALEND
                      AND TC.F_TCALENDSTD = 1
    WHERE  ( C_TPERIOD <> 3
             AND C_TPERIOD <> 9 )
           AND Dateadd(SECOND, 59, Dateadd(MINUTE, 59, Dateadd(HOUR, 23, Dateadd(DAY, -1, Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, P.D_JOUR) + 1, 0)))))  >= Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, - @SM, @DR)), 0)
           AND Dateadd(SECOND, 59, Dateadd(MINUTE, 59, Dateadd(HOUR, 23, Dateadd(DAY, -1, Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, P.D_JOUR) + 1, 0)))))  <= Dateadd(week, Datediff(week, 0, Dateadd(WEEK, 0, @DR)), 0)) T ORDER BY T.YEARS ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: Re "i made something based on a query found on the web but it works on weeks not months." - is it possible that you do not even understand what your code does?

Comment: please edit your question and format the sample data and stable structure info correctly (use the formatting tools above the text editor). Also show the query you have now and the results you currently get, it might help people understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: done and i understand the query but i don't know how to put month instead week